# Unknown Java Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse

`Error: Could not find or load main class HelloNewWorld` which i know has something to do with where i save the project and such, but `Syntax error on Token(s), misplaced Construct(s)
-Syntax error on token ""Hello World"", delete this token` i have never gotten that on another java IDE, btw i just got eclipse, though i well experienced with Java.

Code:

```
package ScratchPackage;

public class ScratchHelloClass {
    System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Read a Java tutorial, your code contains 2 major mistakes even if it has only 3 lines.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a `main` method either.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Hello World");
```

This line must be inside a method. The main entry point of Java program is the `public static void main(String[] args)` method signature, so just wrap that line of code in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

You should probably go over the Java tutorials from the beginning: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: This answers to the question, but I don't think we should answer to someone who was not able to find out to write a `Hello world` in Java.

Comment: Omg i totally forgot the Main method xD sry, but the could not load or find main class would have something to do with the save directory right?

Comment: well everything is working find, thx to anything that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

You forgot the main method. : )

Comment: Yeah sry i was just in a hurry to install eclipse and see if everything fince xD